# Variadic template function to create string

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, template-argument-deduction

I'm new to variadic template functions. I have written a simple class, `StringStream`, that has a variadic template function that creates a `std::string` from variable template arguments - strings, ints, etc.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class StringStream
{
public:
    StringStream() = default;
    ~StringStream() = default;

    template<typename T>
    std::string Stringify(const T &value)
    {
        mStream << value;
        return mStream.str();
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    std::string Stringify(const T& value, Ts... values)
    {
        mStream << value;
        return Stringify(values...);
    }

private:
    std::stringstream mStream;
};
```

What I want to do now is use a `std::string` member in `StringStream` instead of `std::stringstream` and build the string from the arguments of `Stringify()`. For arguments that are not `std::string` I want to convert to strings with `std::to_string()`, otherwise I just concatenate the argument. I am running into a compiler error. Here's my modified class:

```
class StringStream
{
public:
    StringStream() = default;
    ~StringStream() = default;

    template<typename T>
    std::string Stringify(const T &value)
    {
        mString += std::to_string(value);
        return mString;
    }

    template<>
    std::string Stringify<std::string>(const std::string& value)
    {
        mString += value;
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    std::string Stringify(const std::string& value, Ts... values)
    {
        mString += value;
        return Stringify(values...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    std::string Stringify(const T& value, Ts... values)
    {
        mString += std::to_string(value);
        return Stringify(values...);
    }

private:
    std::string mString;
};
```

My compiler error says:

error C2665:  'std::to_string': none of the 9 overloads could convert all the argument types

I am calling the function like this:

```
int main()
{
    int age;
    std::cin >> age;
    StringStream ss;
    std::cout << ss.Stringify("I", " am ", age, " years ", "old") << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Things written in double quotes are `const char*`, not `std::string`. You need to handle that separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is that, string literals (`"I"`, `" am "`, `" years "`, `"old"`) are arrays of constant `char`s (`char const [N]`, for some `N`). You can intercept they as `char const *` but not as `std::string`.

A little off topic, I suppose, but I give you two suggestions:

(1) divide `Stringify()` in two function: the variadic one, `public`, that call a `private` one (`toStr()`, in my following example) to make conversion over singles arguments

(2) avoid recursion for the variadic version of `Stringify()` but simply use pack expansion.

I mean... you can write `Stringify()` as follows

```
  template <typename... Ts>
  std::string Stringify (Ts const & ... vals)
   {
     using unused = int[];

     (void)unused { 0, (mString += toStr(vals), 0)... };

     return mString;
   }
```

or, if you can use C++17, using template folding

```
  template <typename... Ts>
  std::string Stringify (Ts const & ... vals)
   { return ((mString += toStr(vals)), ...); }
```

For `toStr()`, I propose a template version that uses `std::to_string()` but enabled only when the template `T` type isn't convertible to `std::string`

```
  template <typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<
     false == std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value,
     std::string>::type toStr (T const & val)
   { return std::to_string(val); }
```

and the non-template version that accept a `std::string`

```
  std::string toStr (std::string const & val)
   { return val; }
```

This way, if an argument is directly convertible to `std::string` (is `std::string` or another type that can be used to construct a `std::string`) the non-template version is called; otherwise is called the template one.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class StringStream
 {
   private:
      std::string mString;

      template <typename T>
      typename std::enable_if<
         false == std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value,
         std::string>::type toStr (T const & val)
       { return std::to_string(val); }

      std::string toStr (std::string const & val)
       { return val; }

   public:
      StringStream() = default;
      ~StringStream() = default;

      template <typename... Ts>
      std::string Stringify (Ts const & ... vals)
       {
         using unused = int[];

         (void)unused { 0, (mString += toStr(vals), 0)... };

         return mString;
       }
 };

int main ()
 {
   int age = 42;
   StringStream ss;
   std::cout << ss.Stringify("I", " am ", age, " years ", "old") << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should continue to use `stringstream`, concatenating strings using `+` is inefficient, since you copy the entire string for every `+` operation.

Just convert the result to a string before your function exits. You don't need an instance of a class.:

MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename... TArgs>
std::string Stringify(const TArgs&... args) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    (ss << ... << args);
    return ss.str();
}

int main()
{
    int age;
    std::cin >> age;
    std::cout << Stringify("I", " am ", age, " years ", "old") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I like it. This is using a fold expression that comes with C++17.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `to_string` inside

```
template<typename T>
std::string Stringify(const T &value)
{
    mString += std::to_string(value);
    return mString;
}
```

so you can remove `to_string` from `Stringify(const T& value, Ts... values)`, and replace it by just `Stringify`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::string Stringify(const T& value, Ts... values)
{
    mString += Stringify(value);
    return Stringify(values...);
}
```

add also specialization for const char*:

```
std::string Stringify(const char* value)
{
    return mString += value;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mgVwZF)

Now your problem is that `const char[2]` is passed `to_string`, but `to_string` doesn't have overload which accepts that input. By replacing `to_string` by `Stringify` an appropriate overload can be used for first argument from arguments pack.

Comment: I had to change mString += Stringify(value) to just Stringify(value) then I got the result I wanted. However, if I just call Stringify() with a std::string parameter I get a compiler error.

Comment: @jignatius You are getting error because there is no overload `Stringify` which takes no args. You can add `std::string Stringify() { return ""; }` but I don't know if it is what you want, empty string is returned. When all parameters from pack were unpacked `Stringify` is called with empty list.

Comment: Now I get stackoverflow!

Comment: @jignatius Check [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/90Ic3b), it is simpler version what you want.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. So no template specialisation required for std::string?

Comment: Specialization is not required, if compiler has to choose between two methods (which have the same match): one is templated version, and the other is normal member function, always normal version is selected.